# Trying to get MySQL-python working for django using apache/FastCGI with no root access

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv, fastcgi

My overall goal is to get django running on a server for which I don't have root access.  I have convinced the admin to install mod_fcgid on the main apache server, but that is basically all I can do from the root side.

After a lot of struggling, my current setup is to create a virtualenv, install django, flup and MySQLdb-python in the virtualenv and make a "mysite.fcgi" script in a web accessible directory for which the .htaccess file uses fastcgid for .fcgi files.  This all works and when I use a browser to load mysite.fcgi, then my django project is successfully reached - I know this because I get a django error page (instead of the countless "premature end of script headers" 500 pages I was getting while trying to figure out all the paths).

So, the django error page I am getting says:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /
Error loading MySQLdb module: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, I know that everything basically works, since I can do "python manage.py runserver" as long as I add this line to my bash shell before running:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/alternate_versions/mysql-5.5.11/lib
```

Thus, I tried adding this to my .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/alternate_versions/mysql-5.5.11/lib
```

But, that does not affect my django error message (other than showing the correctly set environment variable in the bottom of the django debug screen).  I don't know why this doesn't work.

This leads me back to the MySQLdb-python package.  I built that by downloading the source and running "python setup.py build" and "python setup.py install" from within my virtualenv.  However, **THIS IS MAYBE THE KEY PROBLEM**: *I need to use a mysql installation which is not the system default!*  The default installation does not have the source nor the mysql_config command.  The alternate install is newer and has the source/devel version, which is required for mysql-python.  So, in the site.cfg file for MySQLdb-python I had to specify the mysql_config variable to point at the alternate mysql installation:

```
mysql_config = /opt/alternate_versions/mysql-5.5.11-src/scripts/mysql_config
```

When I run mysql_config using the --libs option, it is (correctly?) pointing to the directory in which the libmysqlclient.so.18 file lives:

```
-L/var/alternate_versions/mysql-5.5.11/lib -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -ldl
```

Ideas for moving forward:

Is there an alternate way to build the MySQLdb libraries?  I tried the various options in the site.cfg file (static=True, embedded=True), but this doesn't work either.  I didn't try all combinations of those options, since I don't really know what they are doing.

Can I manually add the path to the MySQLdb library?  I think it is in an egg file, which I have no idea how to modify.

If MySQLdb was installed as root, would that make a difference?  I want to be confident in this option before asking the admin to try it.  We still have the problem of needing the alternate mysql installation.

Is there a different way to specify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH for apache?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Yep, didn't work unfortunately.  I've used pip but don't really know - does it just download then run setup.py?  Or does it do more?

Comment: Its a really good tool for managing python packages :D http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved my problem by cheating.  I downloaded a rpm for my version of Suse, got out the files using this command:

```
rpm2cpio python-mysql-1.2.2-1.79.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

Then, I copied all the files to my virtualenv directory:

```
cp -pir ./usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/* ../virt/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
```

And, it worked!